# Make SSH_AUTH_SOCK be the same file every time

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ssh-agent

I need to be able to make ssh-agent use the same file for it's socket every time I log in. Currently it uses a random file in a temp folder, and this is causing issues for a systemd service in vagrant.

We run a command to create an env file that defines the socket file location for systemd to use, yet it keeps changing location on every log in, and therefore after vagrant provisions, the location written to the env file has changed, and is no longer valid.

Is there any way I can force it to always be `/etc/ssh/ssh_auth_socket` for example?

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible with default `ssh-agent`. It creates also file in `$TMPDIR/ssh-XXXXXXXXXX/agent.<ppid>` as noted in manual page. It is to make sure the socket secure (not accessible only by your user).

But you can use `gnome-keyring`. They create socket in `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`, so it is in secure place and uses the same protocol (common in Gnome desktops).

What do you need it for? If you have the path in variable, you can simly create `.bashrc` to create symlink from your "known" location to the real place.

Comment: It's a bit of a pain. We need an autossh tunnel creating to another server to mimic a networked machine for a vagrant testing box. The problem is we are a team with different rsa keys and so we use ssh agent forwarding to make it work, but systemd has no access to the agent. I think I need to re-imagine this scenario some other way :(